# Splitting data from original column to two new columns based on string match in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i am trying to split data between two new columns based on string match in csv file. Input file looks like below.

```
ID  Service Type
10  Parts warranty
20  Service warranty
30  Parts warranty
10  Service warranty
30  Service warranty
20  Parts warranty
```

If 'Service Type' column data matches Parts Warranty it should move to new columns 'Parts' and if 'Service Type' column data matches Service warranty then it should move to new 'Service' column and delete the original column 'Service Type'.

```
ID  Parts           Service
10  Parts warranty  Service warranty
20  Parts warranty  Service warranty
30  Parts warranty  Service warranty
```

Any help is appreciated as i am new to Pandas and python and want to figure this out for a new code i am working on.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.pivot_table(values='Service Type', columns='Service Type' , index='ID',  aggfunc=lambda k: k.name[-1])

Service Type    Parts warranty  Service warranty
ID      
10              Parts warranty  Service warranty
20              Parts warranty  Service warranty
30              Parts warranty  Service warranty
```

Can always rename if needed

```
.rename(columns={'Parts warranty': 'Parts', 
                 'Service warranty': 'Service'})


Service Type    Parts           Service
ID      
10              Parts warranty  Service warranty
20              Parts warranty  Service warranty
30              Parts warranty  Service warranty
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `pivot` with `assign`

```
df.assign(Type=df['Service Type'].str.split(' ').str[0]).pivot('ID','Type','Service Type')
Out[575]: 
Type           Parts           Service
ID                                    
10    Parts warranty  Service warranty
20    Parts warranty  Service warranty
30    Parts warranty  Service warranty
```